# how can i get second max id in mysql?

Tags: mysql

how can i get second max id in mysql?

see my codes and picture bellow:

[image]

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;

-- ----------------------------
-- Table structure for `a`
-- ----------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `a`;
CREATE TABLE `a` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `name` varchar(30) default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=8 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

-- ----------------------------
-- Records of a
-- ----------------------------
INSERT INTO `a` VALUES ('1', 'jimy');
INSERT INTO `a` VALUES ('7', 'khon');
INSERT INTO `a` VALUES ('3', 'tina');
INSERT INTO `a` VALUES ('4', 'kelvin');
INSERT INTO `a` VALUES ('5', 'ricky');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
select max(id) from a where id != (select max(id) from a)
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the `limit` clause:

```
select *
from a
order by id desc
limit 1, 1
```

Answer (score 2):

I like Gordon Linoff's answer, while providing my ugly clause:

```
select min(id) as id from 
       (select * from a order by id desc limit 2) as temp_table;
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way to fetch second max salary & nth salary

```
select 
 DISTINCT(salary) 
from employee 
 order by salary desc 
limit 1,1
```

Note:

```
limit 0,1  - Top max salary

limit 1,1  - Second max salary

limit 2,1  - Third max salary

limit 3,1  - Fourth max salary
```